# Is it possible to combine Configurable Products With Grouped Products Together On One Listing?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, grouped-products, listing

I have a listing on Magento that requires both Configurable Product and Grouped Product to be both shown on the listing. Is it possible to do this at all?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The listing shows all the products that belong to the current category. In the listing can have all the different product types.